# Website PayPal integration

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, payment

When i redirect the user to this address:

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=sales@mycompany.com&currency_code=AUD&amount=1.0&return=http://mycompany.com/paymentFinished.aspx?

and user makes the payment, then it will redirect to some thing like this:

http://mycompany.com/paymentFinished.aspx?tx=GDUYSGUDYGYWUGU&st=Completed&...

Now i have the tx that is Transaction ID. How can i retrieve information about the TransactionID i just received to verifying that is not fake and created by user?

I do not want to make changes in other parts of application! just need to know how can retrive Transaction Details of given transactionID.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either PDT to validate this information, and verify that it is not fake or you can use the TransactionSearch API to connect to your PayPal account and verify the transaction.  You can find more on PDT [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer).  There are also some sample scripts on that site that you can use as well.  If you want to use the TransactionSearch API you can find information on this [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/transactionsearch-api-operation-nvp) and in the developers guide [here](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_nvpapi_developerguide.pdf) on page 189.